# Replace text in logger message

Tags: python, json, logging

### Problem

I want to json dumps dicts into my log file, starting to the right of the logger info.

- `indent=4`  -- dict is under the logger info and hard to read.
- `indent=35` -- each level is indented 35 spaces -- also tough to read.

I believe the simplest solution is to offset the starting indent in each dict.:

```
   fmt="%(levenlame) - %(message)s".replace('\n', '\n'+" "*30)
```

- has no effect.

#### Example

```py
import json
import logging

# --- Logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)-8s :: %(name)s [ %(lineno)s ]  :: %(message)s".replace('\n', '\n'+' '*30)
)

logger = logging.getLogger('scratch')
logger.debug('Test_1')
logger.debug('Test_2')
logger.debug('Test_3')
test_dict = {'message_type': 'update',
             'date': '03-07-2020',
             'params':
                 {'p_1': 'X',
                  'p_2': 'Y',
                  'p_3': 'Z'}
             }

logger.debug(json.dumps(test_dict, indent=4))
```

### Output

```
# ------------------------
#    Current output
# ------------------------
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 11 ]  :: Test_1
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 12 ]  :: Test_2
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 13 ]  :: Test_3
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 22 ]  :: {
    "message_type": "update",
    "date": "03-07-2020",
    "params": {
        "p_1": "X",
        "p_2": "Y",
        "p_3": "Z"
    }
}


# ------------------------
#    Desired output
# ------------------------
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 11 ]  :: Test_1
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 12 ]  :: Test_2
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 13 ]  :: Test_3
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 22 ]  :: { "message_type": "update",
                                  "date": "03-07-2020",
                                  "params": {
                                      "p_1": "X",
                                      "p_2": "Y",
                                      "p_3": "Z"
                                  }
                              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

-- custom dumps function.

- json.dumps(dict)
- modify string
- return modified string

```py
def dumps(dict_object, name=None):

    r_string = ''
    l_sring = json.dumps(dict_object, indent=4).replace('\n', '\n' + " " * 28 + '| ')
    if name is not None:
        r_string = f'--- {name} ---\n' + " " * 28 + '| '

    return r_string + l_sring
```

---

### Example

```py
# --- Logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)-8s :: %(name)s [ %(lineno)s ]  :: %(message)s"
)

# --- Log to Stream
logger = logging.getLogger('scratch')
logger.debug('Test_1')
logger.debug('Test_2')
logger.debug('Test_3')
test_dict = {'message_type': 'update',
             'date': '03-07-2020',
             'params':
                 {'p_1': 'X',
                  'p_2': 'Y',
                  'p_3': 'Z'}
             }

logger.debug(dumps(test_dict, name='test_dict'))
```

### Result

```
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 23 ]  :: Test_1
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 24 ]  :: Test_2
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 25 ]  :: Test_3
DEBUG    :: scratch [ 34 ]  :: --- test_dict ---
                            | {
                            |     "message_type": "update",
                            |     "date": "03-07-2020",
                            |     "params": {
                            |         "p_1": "X",
                            |         "p_2": "Y",
                            |         "p_3": "Z"
                            |     }
                            | }
```